# Cannot scale or move objects in Object mode

Tags: modeling, object-mode

I cannot scale or move an object while in Object mode. Instead it seems that I am moving the pivot point. Any ideas about how to stop this behavior?

In the screenshot here below, I have added a sphere. When I try to move the sphere using the G key, the pivot point seems to be moved. When I try to resize it, the dimensions stay the same and the scale values change instead.

Any ideas about why is this happening? Also why the XYZ axis are appearing?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You activated the *Affect Only* option in *Sidebar > Tool*.

[image]

Comment: That setting is also available from the little 'Options' dropdown in the top right corner of the 3D viewport.